# How to 'use' packages in my own Laravel middleware?

Tags: php, laravel-5, package, middleware

I wrote a localization middleware in Laravel using the `LaravelGettext` package which looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Locale {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if ($request->method() === 'GET') {
            $segment = $request->segment(1);

            if (!in_array($segment, config('laravel-gettext.supported-locales'))) {
                $segments = $request->segments();
                $fallback = session('locale') ?: config('laravel-gettext.fallback-locale');
                $segments = array_prepend($segments, $fallback);

                return redirect()->to(implode('/', $segments));
            }

            session(['locale' => $segment]);
            LaravelGettext::setLocale($segment);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

I am routing into the middleware via:

```
Route::prefix('{lang?}')->middleware('locale')->group(function () {
    ...
}
```

Running through the middleware gives me this error though:

```
"Class 'App\Http\Middleware\LaravelGettext' not found"
```

So I figured I might have to import the `LaravelGettext` package manually by adding:

```
use Xinax\LaravelGettext\LaravelGettext;
```

Which now gives me this Exception:

```
"Non-static method Xinax\LaravelGettext\LaravelGettext::setLocale() should not be called statically"
```

Which makes me wonder: Is there even a valid option to access the package inside a middleware? Or did I drive into a design flaw here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it just came to me that I had to import the Facade, not the actual class itself. So adding

```
use Xinax\LaravelGettext\Facades\LaravelGettext;
```

made it finally work!